# Need help in designing control system

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system

I tried to design the circuit but it doesn't give out the result that I was expecting and hope for and I am not sure why. Any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Original Transfer Function ^

[image]

Block Diagram

[image: Expecting Result with Matlab simulation]

Expecting Result with Matlab simulation

[image: Circuit design]

Circuit design

[image: Simualted Result]

Simulated Result (green line as input and red line as output)

Comment: Why don`t you use inverting integrators ? The design would be much simpler and will be identical to the well-known Tow-Thomas topology. More than that, in the block diagram the feedback  factors look like "-1" ?

Comment: @Lvw I did it and it works but now how do I turn this to a type 2 system without altering the original circuit

Comment: Gary - please be specific: (1) What did you do? and (2) what do you mean with "type 2 system"? Show us the actual circuir diagram - with parts values and tell us how did you arrive at hese values! Othwerwise, I don`t know how to answer...

Comment: (1) I have done the circuit using the tow-Thomas topology as the original circuit
But now I have to make sure there is no steady-state error for ramp input and as far as I know, there is no steady-state error in a type 2 system and this is a type 1 system

(2) So I think to get rid of the steady-state error I have to turn the circuit to a type 2 system by cascading some circuit at the front or the back of this original tow-Thomas circuit. Since I am not allowed to alter the original function circuit.

Sorry for being vague just then
@Lvw

Comment: Gary - you are using certain expressions (type 1, type 2 system); so I suppose you know what you are talking about...please explain: What do you mean using these terms! I must admit - I do not know ....

Comment: From as far as i know if i am not wrong type 1 system means there is 1 poles at the origins and type 2 system means there are 2 poles at the origin. @Lvw

Comment: OK - so you are speaking about one or two integrators in the circuit.  But - in which circuit? I think, you have a state-variable filter circuit in Tow-Thomas topology...so what is your problem? It is really not clear to me...

Comment: Err this  @Lvw https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468694/control-system-how-to-get-rid-of-steady-state-error-for-ramp-input?fbclid=IwAR2NJhxROCheZgYrGg4kM8acsUdGy-ERLa4QeEVG94Sr0TKZum06tpyjcys

Comment: sorry for being not understandable btw @Lvw